# VS 2015 Publish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I went to go publish my ASP.Net website and this is what I am got. I am trying to figure out why and I have no reason as of yet any ideas ?

Things Tried

- Run as Administrator
- going back to a previous version
- Published a brand new website (this works)

---

```
4>        Done executing task "CopyPipelineFiles" -- FAILED. 4>        Done building target "CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage" in project "POS.UI.csproj" -- FAILED. 4>Done building project "POS.UI.csproj" -- FAILED. 4>
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause is, if you have included some files in the project that are not necessary to compile (like xml files or word files), & then removed the files from the hard drive, but forgot to delete them in the "Solution Explorer" inside Visual Studio - then "Rebuild Solution" will work b/c those files were not necessary to compile - but "Publish" will fail b/c it cannot find those files when Visual Studio tries to copy files to the publish destination.

Comment: There it was, deep down in the project files. I couldn't find it on disk, nor in git...

Answer (score 0):

I found a folder that was almost 70 meg I excluded the folder and it published like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for some time, but as it turns out, I had an (always annoying) thumbs.db file in one of my folders. In the Output window I saw VS complaining about not being able to copy it, but it seemed to continue fine, but then gave me the **"Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped"** message. I removed the **thumbs.db** file and that did the trick.